# How to dynamically find ClientIDs of controls using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dynamic, client-side

I'm working on a javascript function which takes in the names of three controls, then find them on the page.  There are five sets of these controls.  For simplicity, I would like to use the same function and pass in the set of control names, then have the function dynamically find the controls by clientID. Is there a way to do this?

Here's what I have so far...

```
        function InsertKeyword(keywordCtrl, subjCtrl, bodyCtrl) {
            var ctrl;
            if (OnSubj) ctrl = $find("<%=" + subjCtrl + ".ClientID%>");
            if (OnBody) ctrl = $find("<%=" + bodyCtrl + ".ClientID%>");
            if (OnSubj == 1 || OnBody == 1) {
                var selectedIndex = document.getElementById(keywordCtrl).selectedIndex;
                var selectedText = document.getElementById(keywordCtrl).options[selectedIndex].text;
                var strSpan = '<u>' + selectedText + '</u>&nbsp';
                ctrl.pasteHtml(strSpan);
            }
        }
```

This doesn't work, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

**How do you dynamically find the ClientIDs of controls using javascript?**

Comment: I think you're mixing up how client-side and server-side work... `<%= %>` is a server side command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= %>` is server-side, not client-side code, so instead of...

```
if (OnSubj) ctrl = $find("<%=" + subjCtrl + ".ClientID%>");
if (OnBody) ctrl = $find("<%=" + bodyCtrl + ".ClientID%>");
```

You should have something like...

```
if (OnSubj) ctrl = $find("<%=subjCtrl.ClientID%>");
if (OnBody) ctrl = $find("<%=bodyCtrl.ClientID%>");
```

Where `subjCtrl` and `bodyCtrl` are actual server-side control objects.

The only way you could get your JavaScript to work was if you CALLED the function something like this...

```
InsertKeyword("my keyword", "<%=subjCtrl.ClientID%>", "<%=bodyCtrl.ClientID%>");
```

And then had your JavaScript something like...

```
function InsertKeyword(keywordCtrl, subjCtrl, bodyCtrl) {
  var ctrl;
  if (OnSubj) ctrl = $find(subjCtrl);
  if (OnBody) ctrl = $find(bodyCtrl);
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment by the OP, it is not possible to use the `<%= %>` syntax when declaring `OnClientClick` attribute on a server-side control *via the mark-up*.

The following will not work, and the `<%=myCtrl.ClientID%>` will be rendered as exactly that when sent to the browser...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="test" OnClientClick="myFnc('<%=myCtrl.ClientID%>')"/>
```

Instead you need to set the attribute via the code-behind (C# assumed) via one of these methods...

```
test.OnClientClick = "myFnc('" + myCtrl.ClientID + "');";
test.OnClientClick = string.Format("myFnc('{0}');", myCtrl.ClientID);
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I tried it out and only the string "<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>" is passed in, not the control's client id.

Comment: @ks78, are you sure that `<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>` is being processed on the server by ASP.NET?  If it's contained with a `.js` file (for instance) then the file will be simply pumped out to the browser without any processing

Comment: @ks78, remember that only the page / usercontrol containing the server-side control object can provide the `ClientID` (unless of course you have setup a method/property/session variable/etc to retrieve that value)

Comment: The script is on the .aspx page, not in a .js file.  The function is being called from the OnClientClick property of a dropdownlist. For some reason the server isn't processing it and replacing it with the control's clientID.

Comment: @ks78, is `<%=txtSubject.ClientID%>` part of the actual `OnClientClick` attribute?  If so, then it's not possible to have that syntax within the mark-up of the control.  I will update my answer now to explain what I mean

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Setting the attribute in the code behind works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question then I think you want the control's ID in javascript. If you are using Asp.Net 4, then set the controls `ClinetIDMode = Static`. Now in javascript enter the same control id. FOr example if you have a control with ID `myControl` then in javascript you can get it as

```
var cID = document.getElementByID('myControl');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that:

"<%=" + subjCtrl + ".ClientID%>"

You need:

"<%= codeBehindControlID.ClientID %>"

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS selectors to get control matching on the last part of the ASP.NET clientID, like so:

```
$.find('input[name$='+subjCtrl+']:checked');
```

Not tested but it should be something like that.

EDIT:I don't know what controls you are using but this is an example. Can provide a more detailed one if you post your ASP.NET markup as well.

Comment: I don't know much about CSS selectors, but wouldn't that be referring to client-side control names?